# how to check with php if the js validation function returned true or false

Tags: javascript, php

I am doing a PHP WebShop and this is the register page.
Here you can see the js validation function and the html form.

Now I need to know if the user entered a valid input so I can continue and insert this info in the db.

How i can continue from here?

```js
function validateForm() {
 
 //alphabets in hebrew only
 var namepattern=/^[א-ת]+$/;
  var emailpattern =/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*\.([a-zA-Z]{2,4})$/;
 

 //firstName
  var x=document.forms["form1"]["firstName"];
 if (x.value=="")
   {
  document.getElementById('pointfn').innerHTML="*הכנס שם פרטי";
    x.focus();
  return false;
   }
   
   else if ((!namepattern.test(x.value)))
   {
  document.getElementById('pointfn').innerHTML="*ניתן להקליד רק אותיות";
    x.value="";
  x.focus();
  return false;
   }
     document.getElementById('pointfn').innerHTML='';

//LastName
 x=document.forms["form1"]["lastName"];
 if(x.value=="")
   {
  document.getElementById('pointln').innerHTML="*הכנס שם משפחה";
  x.focus();
  return false;
 }
 
  else if ((!namepattern.test(x.value)))
   {
  document.getElementById('pointln').innerHTML="*ניתן להקליד רק אותיות";
    x.value="";
  x.focus();
  return false;
   }
   
   document.getElementById('pointln').innerHTML='';
 //identity
 
  x=document.forms["form1"]["identity"];
 if(x.value=="")
   {
  document.getElementById('pointid').innerHTML="*הכנס מספר תעודת זהות";
  x.focus();
  return false;
 }
 
 
  else if (isNaN(x.value)==true)
    {
  document.getElementById('pointid').innerHTML="*ניתן להקליד רק ספרות";
  x.focus();
  return false;
 }
 
  else if(x.value.length<9)
    {
  document.getElementById('pointid').innerHTML="*נא להקליד מספר בן 9 ספרות";
  x.focus();
  return false;
 }
   document.getElementById('pointid').innerHTML='';
  // creditCard
  
    x=document.forms["form1"]["creditCard"];
 if(x.value=="")
   {
  document.getElementById('pointcard').innerHTML="*הכנס מספר אשראי";
  x.focus();
  return false;
 }
 
 
  else if (isNaN(x.value)==true)
    {
  document.getElementById('pointcard').innerHTML="*ניתן להקליד רק ספרות";
  x.focus();
  return false;
 }
 
  else if(x.value.length<16)
    {
  document.getElementById('pointcard').innerHTML="*נא להקליד מספר בן 16 ספרות";
  x.focus();
  return false;
 }
   document.getElementById('pointcard').innerHTML='';
   //email
   
    x=document.forms["form1"]["email"];
 if(x.value=="")
 {
  x.value="";
  document.getElementById('pointemail').innerHTML="*הכנס כתובת דואר אלקטרוני";
  x.focus();
  return false;
 }
 else if(!emailpattern.test(x.value))
 {
  x.value="";
  document.getElementById('pointemail').innerHTML="*נא הכנס כתובת נכונה";
  x.focus();
  return false;
 }
 document.getElementById('pointemail').innerHTML=""
  
//password

    x=document.forms["form1"]["password"];
 if(x.value=="")
   {
  document.getElementById('pointpass').innerHTML="*הכנס סיסמה";
  x.focus();
  return false;
 }
 document.getElementById('pointpass').innerHTML=""
 
 //phoneNumber

    x=document.forms["form1"]["phoneNumber"];
 if(x.value=="")
   {
  document.getElementById('pointphone').innerHTML="*הכנס מספר טלפון";
  x.focus();
  return false;
 }
 
   else if (isNaN(x.value)==true)
    {
  document.getElementById('pointphone').innerHTML="*ניתן להקליד רק ספרות";
  x.focus();
  return false;
 }
 
  else if(x.value.length<7)
   {
  document.getElementById('pointphone').innerHTML="נא להקליד מספר בן 7 ספרות";
  x.focus();
  return false;
 }
 
 document.getElementById('pointphone').innerHTML=""

 
  //zip

    x=document.forms["form1"]["zip"];
 if(x.value=="")
   {
  document.getElementById('pointzip').innerHTML="הכנס מיקוד";
  x.focus();
  return false;
 }
 
   else if (isNaN(x.value)==true)
    {
  document.getElementById('pointzip').innerHTML="*ניתן להקליד רק ספרות";
  x.focus();
  return false;
 }
 
   else if(x.value.length<7)
   {
  document.getElementById('pointzip').innerHTML="נא להקליד מספר בן 7 ספרות";
  x.focus();
  return false;
 }
 
 document.getElementById('pointzip').innerHTML=""

 
   //city

    x=document.forms["form1"]["city"];
 if(x.value=="")
   {
  document.getElementById('pointcity').innerHTML="הכנס עיר";
  x.focus();
  return false;
 }
 
   else if ((!namepattern.test(x.value)))
   {
  document.getElementById('pointcity').innerHTML="*ניתן להקליד רק אותיות";
    x.value="";
  x.focus();
  return false;
   }
 
 document.getElementById('pointcity').innerHTML=""
 
   //mailBox

    x=document.forms["form1"]["mailBox"];
 if(x.value=="")
   {
  document.getElementById('pointbox').innerHTML="הכנס תא דואר";
  x.focus();
  return false;
 }
 
   else if (isNaN(x.value)==true)
    {
  document.getElementById('pointbox').innerHTML="*ניתן להקליד רק ספרות";
  x.focus();
  return false;
 }
 
 document.getElementById('pointbox').innerHTML=""

 return true;

 }
```

```html
<form name="form1" METHOD="POST" ACTION="Register.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()"  >
<div >
<table cellspacing="15px" class="box" align="center">



<tr>
   <td> שם פרטי:</td>    <td><input type="text"name="firstName"maxlength="20"></td><td width="300px"><i style="color:red;" id="pointfn"></i></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>שם משפחה:</td>   <td><input type="text"name="lastName"maxlength="20"></td><td width="300px"><i style="color:red;" id="pointln"></i></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
  <td> מספר ת"ז:</td>    <td><input type="text"name="identity"maxlength="9"></td><td width="300px"><i style="color:red;" id="pointid"></i></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
  <td>מספר אשראי:</td>    <td><input type="text"name="creditCard"maxlength="16"></td><td width="300px"><i style="color:red;" id="pointcard"></i></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
 <td> כתובת דוא"ל: </td>  <td> <input type="text"name="email"maxlength="40"></td><td width="300px"><i style="color:red;" id="pointemail"></i></td>
</tr>
  <tr>
 <td> סיסמה: </td>  <td> <input type="text"name="password"maxlength="20"></td><td width="300px"><i style="color:red;" id="pointpass"></i></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td>מספר פלאפון:</td>  <td> <input type="text"maxlength="7"name="phoneNumber">  
    <select name="num">  
    <option value="1">050</option>  
    <option value="2">052</option>  
    <option value="3">054</option>
    <option value="4">057</option> 
 </select></td>
 <td width="300px"><i style="color:red;" id="pointphone"></i></td>
 </tr>
 <tr> 
<td>מיקוד:</td>         <td> <input type="text"maxlength="7"name="zip"></td><td width="300px"><i style="color:red;" id="pointzip"></i></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>עיר:</td>          <td>  <input type="text"maxlength="40"name="city"></td><td width="300px"><i style="color:red;" id="pointcity"></i></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ת.דואר: </td>        <td> <input type="text"maxlength="4"name="mailBox" ></td><td width="300px"><i style="color:red;" id="pointbox"></i></td>
</tr>
<tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="אישור" name="ok"></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
 
</form>
```

Comment: simple: you don't. client-side validation is good for immediate feed-back to the user. But you can never EVER trust client-side validation, because it's too easy to forge. You **ALWAYS** validate on the server, even if it's just "duplicating" what happened on the client. clients lie - you can't trust them.

Comment: This should be an answer -- I'd up-vote it

Comment: iam doing this webShop for school,so i wont sell it or anything? how bad it will be if i still keep this validation?and how i can continue from here if u still think i have to it all with php can i see example?